# Как добавить кнопки с выводом текста на компоненты моей 3д модельки?

Tags: three.js

Это мой проект - дрон. Я хочу добавить кнопки с выводом текста на компоненты моей 3д модельки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь сделать вот так, как на примерах, только расположить эти кнопки на компоненты дрона (аккумулятор, камера, пропеллеры)
//sketchfab.com/3d-models/jurassic-aquarium-diorama-with-annotations-d82bea156a1c4176b5d09b82b176e84c
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/sir-frog-chrono-trigger-0af0c15e947143be8fab274841764bf1

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, переведите вопрос на русский, или задайте его на enSO, иначе вопрос будет закрыт.